# Android-Hello World

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm currently learning how to create android applications so I started with the basic "Hello World" tutorial over at the Android Developers home page. The code is quite simple but when I run it(I'm using Eclipse and a AVD v2.2), it only shows "Android." It does not go to the Home Screen. I updated everything and I still get the same problem. Is there something I did not or

New errors:

```
[2010-09-29 09:35:04 - DeviceMonitor]Sending jdwp tracking request failed!

[2010-09-29 09:41:50 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2010-09-29 10:16:23 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-09-29 10:16:28 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2010-09-29 10:20:27 - HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2010-09-29 10:20:27 - HelloAndroid] (null)
[2010-09-29 10:20:29 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: The first time I ran the simulator it took my computer almost 10 minutes to display the program within the simulator. It has to configure everything for the first time run, so maybe give it a little more time.

Comment: Yeah..it's been up from the time I posted this question...well before that.

Comment: I had the same start-up time as Scott; it simply takes a few minutes on initial load.  People have discussed this issue in the following thread as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator.  Make sure you don't restart your emulator every time you want to run your code. You can Run (f11, ctrl+f11) your project with the emulator up, and the ADB will reload your code on the device.

Comment: you have forgotten to pick the answer

Comment: sometimes "run  again" fixes the problem

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are using the emulator.  You have to be patient; it takes a very long time to start up (several minutes.)  You can start the emulator manually by going to the Window menu in Eclipse, selecting "the Android SDK and ADB manager," clicking on the emulator you created and then clicking on the Start button.  Wait until you see the home screen.  If necessary, unlock it by clicking and dragging the mouse down over the screen until it's unlocked.

If you have access to a physical phone and USB cable, you will have a much better (faster) experience overall.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah after 4+ hours it still shows the "Android" screen. I am just going to use a phone for this.

Comment: No, it shouldn't take any more than 5 minutes.  If it is hung after that, did you try closing the emulator and manually starting it like I suggested with the window option?  If this doesn't work, try setting the Wipe User Data checkbox before startup.  Also, so you know, you only have to do this once until you reboot your PC or if somehow the emulator becomes corrupted.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late but yeah the Wipe User Data did the trick.

Comment: The key point is setting of the "Wipe User Data checkbox before startup." option.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and was bugged by it for two days. but this is what worked for me. one you get this error. try running your project (APP) again. it did the trick for me.

I had done everything. digged the web, installed and re-installed everything 4-5 times including the JDK as well. m not sure if it will help in the long run, but it seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

As for me, I had the same problem and it helped to increase SD volume and max VM app heap size. (Android SDK and AVD manager - Virtual device - Edit) What is interesting, the back change of SD and heap to the previous values is OK, too. That means, that any change of emulator parameters and its rebuilding is enough. (Simple restart won't help)

Definitely, it is cheaper, than total reinstalling. :-)

Answer (score 2):

unlock the screen from the emulator.  That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

go to the run configurations and select target tab. under this tab you can see your targets. then select automatically radio button and select a check box of AVD. then try to run, most probably your issue will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is how I resolved.

if you run

> adb devices

I had nothing on the list. So did.

> adb kill-server

and

> adb start-server

Now if you run the emulator again, the Activity oncreate event will hook properly.
Not sure if this is intended but on the first run on the emulator does not work.
And someone confirm on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem I was running Android 3.1 Java 1.6 on Eclipse. Just rerun the build process and it kicks in the second time.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered error when followed instructions, so i ran "adb logcat" which showed that it is not able to find the class.

In the instructions(tutorial) - : It has been said that (during create new project or class)application name set to Hello World and activity name became HelloWorldActivity.

So if you maintain both CreateActivity name and application name both same, then it might work.

I have increased the AVD RAM size to 1024 and VM application to 36 0r 48 or 24.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone getting following error,

[2010-09-29 09:35:04 - DeviceMonitor]Sending jdwp tracking request failed!

[2010-09-29 09:41:50 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2010-09-29 10:16:23 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-09-29 10:16:28 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2010-09-29 10:20:27 - HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2010-09-29 10:20:27 - HelloAndroid] (null)
[2010-09-29 10:20:29 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!

Simply restart your application.
Wait for some time.Bcaz it take some time.
when you will get screen with "Data-time-charging-lock",
click on lock .There will be some animation.Again click on same lock.
AND Your Are DONE.You will get output..........

Comment: @glennviewjeff already gave an equivalent answer. Please do not duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1):

this kept happening to me ... how i solved it was to use " adb install  "  in a command prompt ...search for adb.exe if its not in your path.   Make sure the emulator is running by going to run configuration and hitting run.  This starts the emulator without installing your apk file.  After the emulator starts up run the command prompt stuff listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my virtual device with the option **Wipe User Data** checked and then reran my app.  That finally worked for me.

Note that in response to the other comments, I also tried the following:

- Simply restarting the device
- Restarting the device after changing the VM heap size
- Restarting my computer

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out using Android Studio's AVD. That AVD seems to work better for me.