# android-failed-to-install--apk-on-real device-null-error

Tags: android

I have similar problem to
   [Android Failed to install HelloWorld.apk on device (null) Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229906/android-failed-to-install-helloworld-apk-on-device-null-error) ,but I cannot start my app only on real device. On emulator all is OK. Maybe someone faced with this problem and found a good solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: plz check android:targetSdkVersion="__" in your menifest file..

Comment: is your device configured to allow USB debugging?

Comment: disconnect device and connect again it may work but restart your system and do install it will work .

Comment: 1) With targetSdkVersion all is OK
2) With USB debugging all is OK
3) Tried several times.
All worked fine a several days ago, but today I am getting such error.

Comment: I noticed that although eclipse shows this error and application not starts in foreground app is being installed.
Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

`Go to Settings > Applications> Development` and uncheck "USB Debugging". Now check it again. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Oh...my device not appearing in the devices tab after doing that :(