# Failed to install apk on real device

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Like many I get this error but none of the solutions I found here did the job. I don't get this error when installing on an emulator, but I get this error with every app I'm trying to install.

This morning my phone went into save mode. After that I can't install an app anymore. The phone is already out the save mode though.

I don't get any errors in my logcat. Don't know what to do anymore. Could someone help?

It is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511149/android-failed-to-install-apk-on-real-device-null-error), but the only answer he got, I already tried.

Problem solved tanks to LisuBB

Comment: what is the result of the adb command ?

Comment: check unknown source check box in development section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to uninstall app from your device by executing

```
adb uninstall _nameofapp__
```

Try also to restart Android server

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

and then try to install again.

Comment: Run cmd/terminal and go to your Android directory with adb file (propably platform-tools/) then type these commands. If you're using Linux instead of adb type ./adb

Comment: If you use linux, try adb as superuser by `sudo adb start-server`

Comment: when i tried adb kill-server it said *server not running * strange because i didn't close it, but I restarted it and it works again now

Answer (score 0):

check your phone's memory and see if you have enough memory . and restart it and check again.

Comment: got like 200mb left, should be enough?

Answer (score -1):

Does the adb install work?
If so, try to install on an external sdcard through the cmdline.