# What do the errors "Failed to install <name of app>.apk" followed by "Launch canceled!" mean? Is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I get these errors when I click on apps on the emulator, and then it freezes. What do they mean?

```
[2012-08-01 14:49:28 - Tip Calculator] Failed to install Tip Calculator.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
    [2012-08-01 14:49:28 - Tip Calculator] (null)
    [2012-08-01 14:49:28 - Tip Calculator] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this always happen? Maybe you have to stop the current app in the settings of the emulator or delete the same before you try to install the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change your ADB connection timeout setting:

[Android Failed to install HelloWorld.apk on device (null) Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229906/android-failed-to-install-helloworld-apk-on-device-null-error)