# how to fix? I can't run my application its cancelled

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have always getting the below error while run my application.

I tried all solution through google. Still i didn't able to fix my solution.

I restart my eclipse and delete the AVD and create it again and done reset adb also.

Still in getting this error

> ```
>     Failed to install Final.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
>     (null)
>     Launch canceled!
> ```

I can't able to start my homescreen. What is the solution for this?

Comment: what is your system configuration ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Failed to install HelloWorld.apk on device (null) Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229906/android-failed-to-install-helloworld-apk-on-device-null-error)

Comment: Whether u tried in real device..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout

Comment: its not starting...till yesterday its works fine. today only this problem

Comment: @raghunandan i have tried that solution its not working in my case

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994026/failed-to-install-helloandroid-apk-on-device-emulator-5554

Comment: @OneManArmy that's similar error to yours check the link

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793956/android-emulator-wont-run-application-started-from-eclipse

Comment: End the "adb.exe" process from the Task Manager and restart eclipse try again.

Comment: Thanks to all to guide me. Now its works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

in command prompt from `/platform-tools` folder in your `android-sdk`.

Then try launching the application after you see `*daemon started successfully*`.