# android app not installed error

Tags: android, runtime-error

I am trying to run android app, I get below error messages.

```
[2014-06-25 15:52:50 - XYZ_project] ------------------------------
[2014-06-25 15:52:50 - XYZ_project] Android Launch!
[2014-06-25 15:52:50 - XYZ_project] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-25 15:52:50 - XYZ_project] Performing com.activity.XYZ_project.Splash activity launch
[2014-06-25 15:52:50 - XYZ_project] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-06-25 15:53:35 - XYZ_project] Uploading XYZ_project.apk onto device '1B4396DD05B5FD93'
[2014-06-25 15:55:05 - XYZ_project] Installing XYZ_project.apk...
[2014-06-25 15:57:07 - XYZ_project] Failed to install XYZ_project.apk on device '1B4396DD05B5FD93!
[2014-06-25 15:57:07 - XYZ_project] (null)
[2014-06-25 15:57:07 - XYZ_project] Launch canceled!
```

can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT 1**

App gets installed on the phone, but I get above message in the logcat. is this due to less phone memory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Failed to install HelloWorld.apk on device (null) Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229906/android-failed-to-install-helloworld-apk-on-device-null-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could cause of some connection problems with pc. Even if the phone is detected, it might be that the connection failed during installing. It needs only a millisecond to break the connection. Possible solution:

1. Change the usb port( don´t use 3.0 USB Ports)
2. Change usb cable
3. clean the usb connector box on Your phone. Maybe there is some dirt in it
4. Change the connection timeout to a longer time. Change it with: Window-> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB Connection Timeout (ms)

Answer (score 0):

Did you using emulator or real device for installation? 
If real device, please check the drivers installed correctly and you must installed Google usb driver on sdk manager. 
If you're on emulator increase adb device timeout to just 10000ms.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was -

*1) Remove the USB cable.*

*2) Attach the USB cable again.*

*3) Wait for device being connected to PC.*

*4) Run android application.*