# First app won't run

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation

I'm trying to run an app in the android emulator on eclipse and it won't run. It keeps on giving me

> [2014-07-28 12:06:48 - FirstApp] Failed to install FirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
>
> [2014-07-28 12:06:48 - FirstApp] (null)
>
> [2014-07-28 12:06:49 - FirstApp] Launch canceled!

Comment: Emulators can be a little unreliable at times.  Potentially just a restart of the emulator, a clean or the IDE can resolve these issues sometimes.

Comment: This may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229906/android-failed-to-install-helloworld-apk-on-device-null-error

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the emulator has a lower tolerance for timeouts on Launch than a physical device would have. One thing you could do is try creating a "splash" page that will redirect to the actual home screen of the application to give the emulator time to Launch the main activity.

I had this issue when working on a phonegap application - I'm assuming the same principle might apply.